# Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected. Error

Tags: vb.net

The following code fails to compile with this error:

> Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

I can't figure it out. Please help.

```
Dim ExeName As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.Ex ecutablePath)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Application.Ex ecutablePath
```

There is an extraneous space here; remove it.